# Using Type Hints with Brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

After several hours of chasing this error with an AWS Elastic Beanstalk app (Python 3.8), I learned that I can't use type hints with brackets, as seen below. But I don't understand why.

Per the docs, I see type hints as far back as at least 3.5 (I didn't look back further than this).

Does this have to do with the Python version, or something else?

doesn't work:

```
def func(x, y:list[str]):
    pass
```

works:

```
def func(x, y:list):
    pass
```

Comment: The `list` type didn't become generic until Python 3.9; that's why `typing` provided the (now deprecated) `List`. (Same goes for `tuple`/`Tuple`, `dict`/`Dict`, etc.)

Comment: @chepner do you know of a better duplicate than what I turned up?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Found one :) Searching for `__class_getitem__` (which was the change that allowed for generic built-in types) was the key.